# Using decorator in a class to access an attribute in self

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have a class which provides some generic structure for a sequential data processing pipeline. I would like to time the execution of a method, and save that to a dictionary attribute of self (`self.timings`).

```
from functools import wraps
import time

class Pipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.steps = {}
        self.timings = {}

    # Decorator for adding functions to pipeline
    def step(self, step_name):
        def step_decorator(f):
            self.steps[step_name] = f
        return step_decorator

    # Decorator for timing a step
    def time_step(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def timed(*args, **kwargs):
            start = time.time()
            result = f(*args, **kwargs)
            end = time.time()
            self.timings[f.__name__] = end - start
            return result
        return timed

    @time_step
    def example_method(self):
        if 'example_func' in self.steps:
            self.output = self.steps['example_func']()
```

I can instantiate a Pipeline and add a step to it:

```
pipeline = Pipeline()

@pipeline.step('example_func')
def example_func():
    for i in range(10000):
        pass
    return 'Completed!'
```

But when I attempt to run `pipeline.example_method()`, it cannot access `self`:

```
pipeline.example_method()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-8204774a5649> in <module>()
----> 1 pipeline.example_method()

<ipython-input-51-ffb2e95a110a> in timed(*args, **kwargs)
     21             result = f(*args, **kwargs)
     22             end = time.time()
---> 23             self.timings[f.__name__] = end - start
     24             return result
     25         return timed

NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

I have tried adding `self` to the parameters in the `time_step` definition, but that causes another error. Is there a straightforward way of accessing attributes from a decorated method?

Comment: `self` is not a keyword it is a *conventionally* named first argument to functions meant to be methods

Comment: Yes, I understand that - how does that relate to the question?

Comment: Because then why did you expect self to be in scope?

Comment: Sorry, I understand your comment now. Yes it's a good point. Think I just got tied up in knots trying to understand the decorator structure, and missed the obvious error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `@time_step()` decorator is not a bound method, when `@time_step` runs, it is just a function object. No `self` is defined in the function, nor is it defined in the wrapper that this decorator returns.

If you use `time_step()` only on methods, then you can count on the returned wrapper function being bound (it's just another function object in the class body in that case, so is treated like any other function attached to a class and looked up on the instance):

```
def time_step(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def timed(self, *args, **kwargs):
        start = time.time()
        result = f(self, *args, **kwargs)
        end = time.time()
        self.timings[f.__name__] = end - start
        return result
    return timed
```

Note that you do have to pass the `self` argument on to the `f()` call, since `f` is also not bound.

Comment: I had tried adding `self` to `timed()` but it was the passing `self` to the `f()` call that I had missed.